# Can't fire function on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<input class="test removeMe" type="text">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    function isEmpty() {
        if (!$(".test").val()) {
            $(this).removeClass("removeMe");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("addMe");
        }
    }
    isEmpty();
});
```

Please, tell me, where am I wrong?

I want `isEmpty` to fire on load/reload and check if the input has value. If it doesn't, it will remove the `removeMe` class. If it does have some value, it will add `addMe` class to it.

Console is empty, I can't figure it out why this isn't working properly.

**Update:**

Very odd... It does fire proper alert relatively if it is empty or not, but doesn't add/remove classes.
https://jsfiddle.net/37tt3x72/1/

**Update 02**

It does work, but not exactly...
https://jsfiddle.net/37tt3x72/2/
The `this` isn't working... if replace it with the targeted element, than it will work. So the question is remained: **Why `this` isn't working here?**

Comment: Did you include `jquery.min.js` ?

Comment: tell us your full code. Did you check console?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Yes, of course. Version 3.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rory McCrossan** provided with great and informative answer here: [Why "$(this)" doesn't work in the following example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257149/why-this-doesnt-work-in-the-following-example#43257208)

And **adeneo** pointed out on another SO question/answers about how `this` works: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    function isEmpty() {
        if (!$(".test").val()) {
          alert("Empty");
            $(this).removeClass("removeMe");
        } else {       
         alert("not Empty");
            $(this).addClass("addMe");
        }
    }
    isEmpty();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test removeMe" type="text">
```

Comment: I'm totally lost, lol :) How can that be... And btw: you missed the `;` after first `alert`.

Comment: No, it is not :) Or at least I'm not so convenient about it :) Try to implement styles to it and you will see it doesn't work as intended... But it does fire the proper alert... I don't get it.  https://jsfiddle.net/37tt3x72/

Answer (score 0):

Call function from document on ready function.

```
function isEmpty() {
    if (!$(".test").val()) {
        $(this).removeClass("removeMe");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("addMe");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  isEmpty();
});
```

Comment: this means store current element reference,in your case there is no any reference that's why not work.