# Why "$(this)" doesn't work in the following example

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<!-- try to change the value="" -->
<input class="test" type="text" value="">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {

        if (!$(".test").val()) {
        alert("Empty");
            $(this).addClass("removeMe");
        } else {
        alert("not Empty");
            $(this).addClass("addMe");
        }

});
```

Why `$(this)` doesn't work here? And what is it possible to do about it if, say there's more than one element(`.test`) to include, for example 3: `if (!$(".test, .test2, .test3").val()) {`

Comment: `this` is function scoped, in your example the closest function is the DOM-ready function, there's no function setting `this` to whatever you think it should be.

Comment: This code just runs once. Did you want to run it at every change of the input? (Hint)

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work" ? Seems to be alerting "empty" which is correct in this case.

Comment: because inside your closure this mean global window object which does not have any addClass method

Comment: @LorDex it doesn't add the classes

Comment: ah ok, I see :)

Comment: @trincot Yes, thanks, I know :)

Comment: @adeneo Thank you for pointing to the right direction. Will learn new things :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because the code runs directly within the document.ready handler and is therefore within the scope of the `document`, hence `this` refers to the `document`.

To achieve what you require you would be best to cache a selector and use that again to add the required class, like this:

```
$(function () {
  var $test = $('.test');

  if (!$test.val()) {
    console.log("Empty");
    $test.addClass("removeMe");
  } else {
    console.log("not Empty");
    $test.addClass("addMe");
  }
});
```

> What is it possible to do about it if, say there's more than one element to include, for example 3: `if (!$(".test, .test2, .test3").val()) {`

In that case you'd need to test each element individually:

```
if (!$('.test1').val() && !$('.test2').val() && ... ) {
```

Comment: Yep, my bad. Corrected

Comment: This code won't work as expected if there is more than one input with class `test` because `.val()` will only consider the very first element

Comment: @devnull69 that's true. Although the OP does state he's giving his element different class names: `for example 3: if (!$(".test, .test2, .test3")`

Comment: @devnull69 Yes, that's what I'm trying to test right now with Rory's example and using `this`, but doesn't work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, but can you show please how would it be possible to use multiple selectors inside the `$test` and use `this` accordingly?

Comment: Just added that to the answer for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, noticed. Thank you. So there's no chance of making it more dynamic with `this`? Perhaps some other approach or something, because this isn't effective... I will repeat my self multiple times

Comment: If you're using unique classes, then no. A better way would be to put the same class on all the elements and loop through them with `each()`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/8rbuuv9d/2/

Comment: The logic in the each is incorrect and the colour in your CSS class is missing the #. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/8rbuuv9d/3/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did it my self! :D https://jsfiddle.net/8rbuuv9d/4/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But thank you, very, very much! :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you once again for correcting and pointing out on the mistakes :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Here's a more simplified version using `toggleClass()`: https://jsfiddle.net/8rbuuv9d/5/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Amazing!